# Jenkins Pipeline - How to fix syntax error in matrix section?

Tags: jenkins, matrix, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I've been trying to configure a matrix section in a declarative pipeline, but it keeps failing.

In the [official documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix), it states:

> Stages in Declarative Pipeline may have a matrix section defining a multi-dimensional matrix of name-value combinations to be run in parallel.

This is my (simplified) pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'production-linux' } // Set where this project can run

    stages {
        stage("do something") {
            matrix {
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'foo'
                        values 'bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3'
                      }
                  }
                stages{
                    stage("using $foo"){
                        steps{
                            step {
                              echo "using variable: $foo"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run it, I get the following:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 14: Unknown stage section "matrix". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block. @ line 14, column 9.
           stage("do something") {
           ^

WorkflowScript: 14: Expected one of "steps", "stages", or "parallel" for stage "do something" @ line 14, column 9.
           stage("do something") {
           ^
```

Has the Matrix section been deprecated?

Comment: What version of the declarative pipeline plugin do you have installed? Try upgrading it to v1.5 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

> Has the Matrix section been deprecated?

No it has not. The exception tells that it found a syntax error.

Your syntax error appears here:

```
steps{
     step {
         echo "using variable: $foo"
     }
}
```

Quoting the [official documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#steps):

> The steps section defines a series of one or more steps to be executed
>   in a given stage directive.

Unfortunately there is no `step`-keyword directly, every command you execute in the `steps` is basically a `step`. To fix your syntax error try the following:

```
steps{
     echo "using variable: $foo"
}
```

Comment: Even if you correct it to remove the `step` it still has the same error. The example in the docs ( https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#matrix-cell-directives ) fails with 
```
WorkflowScript: 7: Unknown stage section "matrix". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block. @ line 7, column 9.
           stage('BuildAndTest') {
           ^

WorkflowScript: 7: Expected one of "steps", "stages", or "parallel" for stage "BuildAndTest" @ line 7, column 9.
           stage('BuildAndTest') {
           ^
```

Comment: nm .. looks like my issue is this is a recently released feature that requires v1.50 of the declarative pipeline plugin: https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/

Comment: Yes, you are right it seems only available in one of the beta builds. There is also a matrix plugin existing: https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-project not sure whether this may help you.

Comment: v1.5 is out of beta. I got our server upgraded last night and matrix is now working for me.

Comment: great! I am glad to hear this :)